# Differentiability of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, derivatives

> Is series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nx} \cos{nx}$$ differentiable on $(0,\infty)$?

I had this question on my exam and didn't solve it.

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum \cos (nx)e^{-nx}$ is uniformly convergent in $[a,b]$ if $0<a<b<\infty$.  So is the derived series $\sum (-n\sin (nx) e^{-nx} -n\cos (nx) e^{-nx})$ because it it dominated by $\sum  2ne^{-na}$ which converges by ratio test. These two fact are enough to conclude that $\sum \cos (nx)e^{-nx}$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$  and its derivative is $-\sum n\sin (nx) e^{-nx}$  if $0<a<b<\infty$. Since $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary we are done.

Comment: you didn't derive well.

Comment: @alans Thank you very much. I have corrected the proof.